# In Pytorch, how to one-hot encode a grayscale image like this for semantic segmentation?

Tags: image, pytorch, encode

I'm using the pretrained DeeplabV3 model for image segmentation, and it gives me an output with shape BxCxWxH, where B=batch size, C=number of classes, W=Width and H=Height. If I take the depth-wise argmax of this output image, I get a WxH result, where every pixel represents a class. For this output image, I have a grayscale image as label, with WxH shape. Howewer, the pixel values in the grayscale label image are not in the range of 0 to number of classes, but in 0.0xx to 0.2, so I can't use it to calculate the loss. To do it, I have to one-hot encode the label image, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, the label image has the following values:

```
tensor([[[0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0431, 0.0431, 0.0317],
         [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0431, 0.0431, 0.0317],
         [0.0824, 0.0824, 0.0824,  ..., 0.0431, 0.0431, 0.0317],
         ...,
         [0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0275,  ..., 0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0317],
         [0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0275,  ..., 0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0317],
         [0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0275,  ..., 0.0275, 0.0275, 0.0317]]])
```

with 14152 unique pixel values. The size of the image is 1024x1024. How could I one-hot encode this image?

The Dataset is the KITTI Semantics Pixel level.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i got the problem finally:  Accidentally, I resized the input ground-truth image by passing it to a torchivison.transforms instance, making it into a reshaped tensor with lots of pixel values. Without this operation, I got the normal pixel values for the ground truth image.